# postgresql application server could not be contacted in ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm try to use pgAdmin4 in ubuntu 16.04. But I find this error: "postgresql application server could not be contacted". I don't find a solutions for ubuntu. Only for Windows platform.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nobJq.png)

Install procedure:

```
sudo apt-get install curl ca-certificates 

curl postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add - 

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list' 

sudo apt-get update 

sudo apt-get install pgadmin4

pgadmin4
```

Comment: How did you install pgAdmin4?

Comment: hello Adrian.
I used this comands.
$ sudo apt-get install curl ca-certificates
$ curl https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install pgadmin4
$ pgadmin4

Comment: Added above to original question to make it clearer and also so others don't have to search through comments.

Comment: Have you tried to start with ```sudo pgadmin4```?

Comment: yes. I try with sudo, but the error persist

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to uninstall it and try the wheel version [Wheel](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-python/). That is how I have done it in past, though to be honest I rarely use pgAdmin4. I find the Postgres client ```psql``` a lot handier to use.